# Uninstall Rails 3 with dependencies?

Tags: rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3

I like that Rails 3 is so easy to install: `gem install rails --pre`, and all of the dependencies are automatically installed for you. But, what about uninstalling it? If I just do `gem uninstall rails`, I still have

```
actionmailer (3.0.0.beta3)
actionpack (3.0.0.beta3)
activemodel (3.0.0.beta3)
activerecord (3.0.0.beta3)
activeresource (3.0.0.beta3)
activesupport (3.0.0.beta3)
```

which I want to get rid of. What's the easiest way to do so?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952836/do-i-have-to-manually-uninstall-all-dependent-gems

Answer (score 14, accepted):

if you're planning to upgrade to a newer version of rails, you can do:

```
sudo gem clean
```

or in newer versions

```
sudo gem cleanup
```

after the newer version has been installed, this uninstall **All** older versions of **All** your gems leaving only the latest version in your system.

Note: these days I use RVM gemset and/or bundler to manage my gems, if you're using RVM I find it's a lot simpler this way. For example you can create a new gemset for each project:

```
rvm gemset create project_name
rvm gemset use project_name
bundle install
```

anything goes wrong you can just delete the gemset and start again

```
rvm gemset delete project_name
```

Comment: Thanks, that'll do nicely. It'd be nice if `gem clean` could take a version number as an argument, so I could remove all of the `3.0.0.beta3` stuff in one stroke, but obliterating all old versions is good enough for me.

Comment: This is not exactly the answer to this question. `gem clean`, now `gem cleanup`, just deletes old versions of your gems. For example, let's say you're upgrading from Rails X to Rails Y, and Rails X has a dependency on Foo, but Rails Y doesn't. The first time you do `gem install rails`, Rails X is installed along with gem Foo. The next time you do `gem install rails`, Rails Y is installed. Then, you do `gem cleanup`. The Foo gem is left on your system even though Rails Y doesn't use it. A true `gem uninstall rails` with dependencies would also delete the Foo gem.

Answer (score 3):

Look at deps(optional):

```
gem dependency rails -v=3.0.9
```

Then uninstall all components of the version specified:

```
gem uninstall actionmailer actionpack activerecord activesupport acriveresource rails -v=3.0.9
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this excellent post on removing all Ruby Gems by Ken Nordquist: http://geekystuff.net/2009/01/14/remove-all-ruby-gems/

The command uses pipes to iteratively push a gem list to the uninstall utility. Here is the command:

```
'gem list | cut -d" " -f1 | xargs gem uninstall -aIx'
```

It successfully removed all gems except the following which appear to be permanent fixtures on my Mac:

minitest (1.6.0)
rake (0.8.7)
rdoc (2.5.8)

Comment: Years later and this is still useful in OS X Yosemite. There are more defaults now. Try: `gem list | cut -d" " -f1 | egrep -v "rdoc|psych|io-console|rake|bigdecimal|json" | xargs gem uninstall -aIx`

Answer (score 1):

Check your currently installed version(s):

```
gem list -d rails
```

Then uninstall the version(s) you don't want:

```
sudo gem uninstall rails -v 3.0.0.beta3
sudo gem uninstall actionmailer -v 3.0.0.beta3
```

etc.

I'm still trying to figure out how to completely remove rails 3.0.0.beta3 and all its deps.

Comment: OK, I realize that I could do that; what I was really wondering is, isn't there a way that requires a single command? Like a single `gem` command that means "uninstall everything where the version number is exactly 3.0.0.beta3"?

Comment: @MarkRichman @TrevorBurnham, this is also not recursive. I.e., when you install Rails, it installs ActiveResource, which installs ActiveModel, etc. So, this only goes one level deep (ActiveModel will not get uninstalled.). A true uninstall would uninstall Rails, its dependencies, its dependencies' dependencies, and so on.