# Why doesn't ri know anything about Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ri

```
$ ri link_to
Nothing known about .link_to
```

Actually, it seems that ri knows nothing about Rails. But `ri --list-doc-dirs` shows the Rails folders are included:

```
/usr/share/ri/1.8/system
/usr/share/ri/1.8/site
/root/.rdoc
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/doc/actionmailer-2.3.5/ri
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/doc/actionpack-2.3.5/ri
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/doc/activerecord-2.3.5/ri
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/doc/activeresource-2.3.5/ri
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/doc/activesupport-2.3.5/ri
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/doc/cgi_multipart_eof_fix-2.5.0/ri
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/doc/columnize-0.3.5/ri
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/doc/daemons-1.0.10/ri
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/doc/fastthread-1.0.1/ri
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/doc/gem_plugin-0.2.3/ri
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/doc/json-1.6.3/ri
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/doc/linecache-0.46/ri
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/doc/macaddr-1.0.0/ri
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/doc/mime-types-1.17.2/ri
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/doc/mongrel-1.1.5/ri
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/doc/mongrel_cluster-1.0.5/ri
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/doc/multipart-post-1.1.4/ri
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/doc/postgres-0.7.9.2008.01.28/ri
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/doc/rack-1.0.1/ri
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/doc/rake-0.8.7/ri
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/doc/rbx-require-relative-0.0.5/ri
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/doc/rdoc-3.12/ri
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/doc/rdoc-tags-1.2/ri
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/doc/rest-client-1.6.7/ri
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/doc/ruby-debug-0.10.4/ri
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/doc/ruby-debug-base-0.10.4/ri
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/doc/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.4/ri
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/doc/uuidtools-2.1.1/ri
```

What's wrong with it?

**UPDATE**

I found these yaml files in the folder of `/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/doc/actionpack-2.3.5/ri/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/`:

```
button_to-i.yaml  cdesc-UrlHelper.yaml  current_page%3f-i.yaml  link_to-i.yaml  link_to_if-i.yaml  link_to_unless-i.yaml  link_to_unless_current-i.yaml  mail_to-i.yaml  url_for-i.yaml
```

But in another system where the ri works well, the files are `*.ri`, not `*.yaml`.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried running:

```
gem rdoc rails
```

From the docs:

```
Summary:
  Generates RDoc for pre-installed gems

Description:
  The rdoc command builds RDoc and RI documentation for installed gems.  Use
  --overwrite to force rebuilding of documentation.
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found that the only reliable way of installing the ri docs is this (i.e it installs the latest Rails including the ri docs):

```
sudo gem install rails --pre --ri
```

Comment: Same for me. I uninstalled rails, and I reinstalled with these defaults: `--both --version '>= 0' --rdoc --ri --no-force
    --install-dir /path/to/gems`

Uninstalling rails isn't straightforward because of its dependencies. See this question and answer for help with this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3755847/177524