# Unable to load the EventMachine C extension; To use the pure-ruby reactor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, bundle

i got trouble, in a rails project（redmine2.3), rails version is 3.2

start the project

```
bundle exec thin start -p 8080 -e production -s 5 -d
```

error info

```
(eval):9: warning: already initialized constant Bundler::Dsl::RAILS_VERSION_IS_3
(eval):9: warning: previous definition of RAILS_VERSION_IS_3 was here
(eval):9: warning: already initialized constant Bundler::Dsl::RAILS_VERSION_IS_3
(eval):9: warning: previous definition of RAILS_VERSION_IS_3 was here
Unable to load the EventMachine C extension; To use the pure-ruby reactor, require 'em/pure_ruby'
/var/wtn/vendor/cache/ruby/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:8:in `require': libruby.so.2.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /var/wtn/vendor/cache/ruby/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/rubyeventmachine.so (LoadError)
    from /var/wtn/vendor/cache/ruby/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/wtn/vendor/cache/ruby/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin.rb:7:in `require'
    from /var/wtn/vendor/cache/ruby/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/wtn/vendor/cache/ruby/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.6.2/bin/thin:5:in `require'
    from /var/wtn/vendor/cache/ruby/2.0.0/gems/thin-1.6.2/bin/thin:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/wtn/vendor/cache/ruby/2.0.0/bin/thin:23:in `load'
    from /var/wtn/vendor/cache/ruby/2.0.0/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
```

the same error happens when running `rails -v`

```
rails -v
(eval):9: warning: already initialized constant Bundler::Dsl::RAILS_VERSION_IS_3
(eval):9: warning: previous definition of RAILS_VERSION_IS_3 was here
```

running `bundle exec .....` in the project produces the same error

the problem has solved, see my comment in the third floor , there are the answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails - cannot run app: Unable to load the EventMachine C extension;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824235/rails-cannot-run-app-unable-to-load-the-eventmachine-c-extension)

Comment: not the same, see my comment in the third floor , there are the answer

Answer (score 35):

I was encountering this error message on Windows 10 while trying to use Jekyll's LiveReload feature. The other answers here did not solve the problem completely, or risked having the issue re-occur the next time `bundle install` is run.

My solution (taken from [this site](https://robbinespu.gitlab.io/blog/2020/10/16/jekyll-unable-to-load-the-eventmachine-c-extension/)) was to:

1. Run this console command

   ```
   gem uninstall eventmachine
   ```

   and choose to uninstall `eventmachine-1.2.7-x64-mingw32` gems from your system.
2. Edit `Gemfile` inside your project directory and add this line inside:

   ```
   gem 'eventmachine', '1.2.7', git: 'https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine.git', tag: 'v1.2.7'
   ```
3. Run

   ```
   bundle install
   ```
4. Clean up your jekyll build and cache with command

   ```
   bundle exec jekyll clean
   ```

You can now use the `--livereload` parameter without getting any issue, even if you execute `bundle install` in future.

Comment: Thanks @Simon East

Comment: Thanks, I'm also encountering this error message on Windows 10 while trying to use Jekyll's LiveReload feature and it works for me as well.

Comment: @EvenWonder Hey did you just add the code on the first line of the gem file? bundle exec jekyll clean didn't work for me

Comment: @SarahV.P Hey, have you found out the solution? I think the last line is more appropriate. Besides, `bundle exec jekyll clean`  is just to clean some auto generated files, there is no relationship between them.

Comment: And if this doesn't work, https://stackoverflow.com/a/73913233/259453 might help

Answer (score 33):

If you are using windows

1. Go to this folder `C:\Ruby24-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.4.0\gems\eventmachine-1.2.5-x64-mingw32\lib`
2. open this file eventmachine.rb
3. write this `require 'em/pure_ruby'` in the first line of code in the file

this will make it work with no issues.

Comment: Save my life, uninstall and install do not work for me!

Comment: It gave me the following error - `The ``SortedSet`` class has been extracted from the ``set`` library.You must use the ``sorted_set`` gem or other alternatives. (RuntimeError)`.

On my machine the path to the file you specified is - `C:\Ruby30-x64\lib\ruby\gems\3.0.0\gems\eventmachine-1.2.7-x64-mingw32\lib`

Comment: I also have this issue

Comment: I'm with the same issue here

Comment: worked with ruby-3.0.1 and eventmachine-1.2.7 on macos

Comment: it worked for a while, I received a subsequent error C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7-x64-mingw32/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb:559:in `close': Bad file descriptor

Comment: For MacOS: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/rubyeventmachine.b

Answer (score 21):

For Ruby 2.4 & eventmachine 1.2.6 on Windows 10.

You gotta uninstall first `eventmachine` and then install it again with platform ruby:

```
gem uninstall eventmachine  (select all versions if prompted)

gem install eventmachine --platform ruby
```

Comment: Doesn't work for MacOS for eventmachine 1.2.7

Answer (score 7):

The relevant error message here is the following:

```
Unable to load the EventMachine C extension; To use the pure-ruby reactor, require 'em/pure_ruby'
```

Try to reinstall the `eventmachine` gem:

```
gem uninstall eventmachine
bundle install
```

See [Rails/Ruby Error When Creating Database: Unable to load the EventMachine C extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134033/rails-ruby-error-when-creating-database-unable-to-load-the-eventmachine-c-exten)
 and 
[Rails - cannot run app: Unable to load the EventMachine C extension;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824235/rails-cannot-run-app-unable-to-load-the-eventmachine-c-extension) for more advice on how to deal with this issue.

Comment: what about the warning: (eval):9: warning: already initialized constant Bundler::Dsl::RAILS_VERSION_IS_3
(eval):9: warning: previous definition of RAILS_VERSION_IS_3 was here

Comment: gem uninstall eventmachine   seems got no tips back

Comment: I also tried this but received the exact same error message.

Comment: I am getting this error `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyRemovalException)
    Uninstallation aborted due to dependent gem(s)
`

Comment: @YashuMittal See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952836/do-i-have-to-manually-uninstall-all-dependent-gems for some tips on how to move past this error.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me on Apple Silicon M1 and Rails 6.1

- Full uninstall of eventmachine: `gem uninstall -aIx eventmachine` followed by a `rm -rf vendor/cache`
- Add eventmachine in the project Gemfile and forcing it to be from the master branch latest like this `gem 'eventmachine', :git => 'git://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine.git', :branch => 'master'`
- Run `bundle install`

Answer (score 1):

The problem has fixed.

```
rm vendor/cache/ -rf
bundle install
```

fixed the error

```
remove the Redundant folder in the redmine/plugins
```

fixed the warnings

[This is record of locating and repairing process.](https://ruby-china.org/topics/25912)

thx all!

Answer (score 0):

gem install eventmachine --platform ruby

Comment: Try to explain at least a little?

Comment: Before uninstall eventmachine with `gem uninstall eventmachine`: https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller2/issues/96#issuecomment-434619796